# Is there an application that can show memory usage in a similar manner to top?

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line, memory-usage, monitoring

I would like to leave an application running in my terminal that shows me the memory usage, similar to how `top` shows CPU and other info, and `iotop` shows the top I/O users.

[image: Top and iotop]

Does such an application exist?

*P.S. I know top shows memory usage as well, but I'm talking about sorting by top memory usage and not showing any other info (similar to what `iotop` does).*

Comment: In top press M and it will sort on memory usage. Is that what you're after?

Comment: I'm also slightly unclear what features you want/don't want, but `htop` is the `top` alternative I use.  Although it sounds like maybe you are looking for fewer but more specific features rather than more features?

Comment: @adempewolff exactly. For example iotop does what it says - shows the I/O usage of my applications and nothing else. I want to be able to run say, 'memtop` and just get memory usage %. `htop` is not what I'm looking for - because it shows other things (including CPU usage) that I already get from `top`. I mean, I like htop no doubt (I've used it before), but it's not what I'm looking for in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closest I could find is `memtop`, a Python script available [here](http://code.google.com/p/memtop/downloads/detail?name=memtop-1.0.0.py&can=2&q=) on Google Code.

Screenshot:
[image]

### How to use *memtop*

- It's a Python script, so simply do a `sudo mv memtop-1.0.0.py /usr/bin/memtop.py` and a `chmod +x /path/to/memtop.py` to make it executable
- Default update period is 15 min; use switch `-p 1` to make it 1 minute, etc. (can't go lower than that unless you modify the source)
- Use `-l N`, where N is the number of processes you want to show, depending on the size of your terminal.
- Use `-m` to show "more" information, i.e. the Swap/Page stats at the bottom of the screenshot.

---

#### The *htop* disguised as *memtop* option

If you don't use `htop` otherwise, it's pretty easy to set it up with the F2-setup option to look like `memtop`:

[image]

- *htop* config is stored in `~/.config/htop/htoprc`, so just delete `htoprc` to restore normal *htop*.

Comment: The project just moved to GitHub: https://github.com/MartinThoma/memtop

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about any specific application for monitoring what you want in real time but I did find some information that might be helpful.

First heres a simple command to print this info `ps -e -orss=,args= | sort -b -k1,1n | pr -TW$COLUMNS` (found here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-show-the-memory-usage-per-process-160181/)

Second here is some more info about scripts to do the same:

http://unixlive.editboard.com/t4-memory-usage-retrieval-on-linux-process-wise-and-general

and

http://unixlive.editboard.com/t5-how-much-ram-is-used-per-program

You could write your own script/program to meet your needs. The info you need is all updated in `/proc/` in realtime, but you have to solve two problems:

1. I doubt there is any one file listing all the processes and their memory usage in real time.  Instead every process has it's own files (in `/proc/[pid]/`), and some of the potential files for finding this info are not human readable--although I suspect that `statm` and `status` have the necessary info and are both human readable.
2. Displaying all this information in realtime.  I know very little about bash scripting or programming but to display the information in realtime you would need to use something like a lot of `tail` commands with a pipe to sort/print only the desired information for each process.

Not really a complete answer, but hopefully this gives you some ideas of what you could try.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Try `watch memstat -w` or perhaps `watch free -m` .

Answer (score 1):

htop is pretty great. It's reasonably lightweight (unlike gnome-system-monitor. It makes no sense to me that a system monitoring program should often be the most high-usage program.)

Push F6, then use the arrow keys or mouse to switch to sorting by MEM%.

Comment: While I like this answer, and htop (I've used it before) I'm looking for an app that follows the principle of doing one thing and doing it well (like `iotop`).